# Javascript function Hex decimal Binary

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function for Decimal to Hex to Binary converter. My code works almost complete, only thing is, it gives me one Value twice. e.g. if I want to convert 45 in Hex and in decimal the answer should be --->>!!!!
45 -->  2,D --> 0010,1101

What i am getting is : 45 -->  2,2,D --> 0010,0010,1101

I am very new to Javascript and trying to solve this small problem for two days now. Please help me finding the error i am making thanks. My code is::

```js
a = prompt("Hex - Decimal - Binary converter. Please give a number : ");
var z = a;
document.write("Number = ", a);
document.write("<br/>");
arr1 = []; // To save quotient (not really required)
arr2 = []; // To save Remainder (not really required)
arr3 = []; // To save Hex values (required to display the end result)
arr4 = []; // To save Binary values (required to display the end result)
hex = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'];
bin = [ '0000'       , '0001'       , '0010'       , '0011'
      , '0100'       , '0101'       , '0110'       , '0111'
      , '1000'       , '1001'       , '1010'       , '1011'
      , '1100'       , '1101'       , '1110'       , '1111'
      ];
//var a = 14;
while (a > 15) {
  b = a / 16;
  c = Math.floor(b);
  d = a % 16;
  arr2.unshift(d);
  arr3.unshift(hex[d]);
  arr4.unshift(bin[d]);

  if (c > 15) {
    arr1.push(c);
  } else {
    arr1.push(c);
    arr2.unshift(c);
    arr3.unshift(hex[c]);
    arr4.unshift(bin[c]);
  }
  a = c;
}
if (a < 16) {
  arr2.unshift(a);
  arr3.unshift(hex[a]);
  arr4.unshift(bin[a]);
}
//document.write("");
console.log("Answer = ", arr1, ", ");
//document.write("Answer = ", arr1,", ");
console.log("Answer = ", arr2, ", ");
//document.write("Answer = ", arr2,", ");
console.log("Answer = ", arr3, ", ");
document.write(
  "The given number ",
  z,
  " is in Hexa decimal system : ",
  arr3,
  " "
);
document.write("<br/>");
console.log("Answer = ", arr4, ", ");
document.write("The given number", z, " is in Binary system : ", arr4, " ");
```

Comment: in the loop: `if(c > 15) else arr3.unsihft[hex[c])` then set `a = c`, then do exactly the same thing again with `if(a<16)` - in other words, if you replaced `a` in the final `if()` statement with `c` you would see the same result.

Comment: Thanks I understand my mistake now.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unshifting the last part of the loop twice.  So you get duplicates in your array.  Once here, in the else:

```
  if (c > 15) {
    arr1.push(c);
  } else {
    arr1.push(c);
    arr2.unshift(c);
    arr3.unshift(hex[c]);
    arr4.unshift(bin[c]);
  }
```

And then again here:

```
if (a < 16) {
  arr2.unshift(a);
  arr3.unshift(hex[a]);
  arr4.unshift(bin[a]);
}
```

I would think you could remove that second part.

Comment: You should probably mention the direct correlation to `a = c` as the precursor to why this code produces the dupe. Just a thought.

Comment: @James Thanks James and Randy i have found my error and changed my code. Problem can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information,
Converting a number to hex or binary is native in javascript

```
let x = 45;
console.log(x.toString(16));
console.log(x.toString(2));
```

For numbers toString() accepts a radix as parameter. Any number from 2 to 36 is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you overcomplicate this thing

```js
const
  inNumber = document.querySelector('#in-number')
, oResult  = document.querySelector('#out-result')
, hex =
  ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F']
, bin = 
  [ '0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111'
  , '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111'
  ]
, hexValue = []
, binValue = [];

document.querySelector('#bt-convert').onclick = e =>
  {
  let N = inNumber.valueAsNumber
  hexValue.length = 0
  binValue.length = 0
  do
    {
    let d = N % 16   
    N = (N-d) / 16

    hexValue.unshift( hex[d] )
    binValue.unshift( bin[d] )
    }
  while ( N > 0 )

  oResult.textContent = `   number = ${inNumber.value}\n`
                      + `hex value = ${hexValue.join('.')}\n`
                      + `bin value = ${binValue.join('.')}\n`
  }
```

```html
<h5>Hex - Decimal - Binary converter. Please give a number</h5>
<input type="number" id="in-number" value="1" min="0" > 
<button id="bt-convert">convert!</button>
<br><br>
<pre id="out-result"></pre>
```